# Adding a dashed bottom border to table view cell overlaps with text randomly in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, border

I am using the below code to add a dashed custom bottom border to tableview cells. It is now overlapping with content randomly. Sometimes, the border is not getting displayed.

```
class AppTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    var isBorderAdded = false

    func isBottomBorderAdded() -> Bool {
        return isBorderAdded
    }

    func getBottomBorderShapeLayer() -> CAShapeLayer {
        return self.shapeLayer!
    }

    func setBottomBorderShapedLayer(_ layer: CAShapeLayer) {
        self.shapeLayer = layer
    }
}
```

The extend tableview cell from the above class and calls the below function in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method.

```
func addDashedBottomBorder(to cell: AppTableCell) {
    let color = UIColor.init(red: 191/255, green: 191/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = cell.frame.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: 0)
    shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
    shapeLayer.lineDashPhase = 3.0
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [9,6]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: shapeRect.height, width: shapeRect.width, height: 0), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath
    if (cell.isBorderAdded) {
        cell.shapeLayer!.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    cell.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    cell.isBorderAdded = true
    cell.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

[image: border overlap]

How to display dashed bottom border at the end of each cell properly?

Comment: Select that line view and in property select clip to bounds tick true

Comment: I am adding the line using code. There is nothing in storyboard. So how do I do the same using code?

Comment: If I add `shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true` the line is not getting displayed at all.

Comment: you are using either ImageView or UIView Right? they both have this property like this : self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: Override prepareForResue and remove the line in that method.

Comment: Clip to bounds is checked in the storyboard for both `UIImageView` and `UIView`.

Comment: Are you using self sizing cells?

Comment: I am not sure what that means. I am adding `estimatedRowHeight = 44` and `rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are adding a sublayer in your cell's layer with a fixed position:

```
shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height)
[...]
cell.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

So it doesn't stick to your cell's bottom side.

You could update this layer's position each time the cell's height change, but my suggestion from a performance and simplicity point of view would be use autolayout.

Add a subview at the bottom of your cell, add the constraints to make it stick, and add only once (in awakeFromNib for example if it's designed in IB) the dashedLayer inside.

Comment: I am updating it each time in `cellForRow at index` by calling the `addDashedBottomBorder` method, which should get the current cell's height, but it does not seem to work that way.

Comment: the cell height is not determined in cellForRow, it may be in several other places like heightForCell. If you want to stick with refreshing the layer's position you can override the layoutSubviews function in your cell. Be very careful with this as you may have performance issues.

Comment: Go it thanks. I added a UIImageView at the bottom of the cell with layout constraints instead of dynamically drawing border.